# Trying to use regular expressions in ruby to find specific characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to use regular expressions in a ruby on rails app to search through a given string and find any instances of opening and closing square brackets, (ie [ and ]) and select the contents between the two.

For example:

```
Lorem ipsum [dolor sit] amet...
```

In this string the result would be: `[dolor sit]`

I played around with rubular a bit and found that this more or less does what I want

```
/\[.*?\]/
```

So my question is, how do i match everything within the two square brackets without selecting the brackets themselves? And also how do I actually integrate them into a ruby script?

Regular expressions are totally new ground for me so any help you guys can offer would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What do you really want to match? What should the match be here `Lorem ipsum [do[lor [si[t] amet]`

Comment: Since your new to regular expressions, `/\[(.*)\]/` does exactly what you want for the sample given, but in no way is it the same as `/\[(.*?)\]/`.

Comment: @sln oh right ok, can you explain what the difference is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collecting multiple captures of a regexp is a job for [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan)

```
>> s="Lorem ipsum [dolor sit] [amet] ..."
=> "Lorem ipsum [dolor sit] [amet] ..."
>> s.scan(/\[([^\]]*)\]/).flatten
=> ["dolor sit", "amet"]
```

Comment: That does exactly what I want, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `String#scan`:

```
"Hi [there] how are [you]?".scan(/\[.*?\]/)
 => ["[there]", "[you]"]
```

This method iterates the entire string, returning every match.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the part of the Regex that corresponds to the part of the input that you want to extract inside `()`:

```
str = "Lorem ipsum [dolor sit] amet....".match(/\[(.*?)\]/)
# str --> #<MatchData "[dolor sit]" 1:"dolor sit"> 
str[1] # Will give you 'dolor sit'
```

Note that you can also access the result of the matching via the global variable: `$1` (in general `$i` where `i` represents the index of the matching word).

Comment: it doesnt work when i try to match more than one instance of []. How do I make it match all instances?

Comment: @gregchapple You mean as in: "Lorem ipsum [dolor sit] [amet]..." ? Like you would like to extract: 'dolor sit' and 'amet'?

Comment: yeah exactly! is that possible?